# when a box is unchecked it clears the previously populated text from checkbox

Tags: javascript, jquery

how do I clear the previously populated text from the checkbox when I uncheck the box?

the list below codes is when you check a box and populated text in the text area.

```
$('input:checkbox').click(function(){
    var tb = "#"+$(this).attr('rel');
    if($(this).is(":checked"))
        $(tb).append(this.name + "\n");

        else($(tb)).removeAttr(":checked");
})
```

Comment: Can you please share the HTML code?

Comment: If you are just building a string with newlines in the DOM using `$(tb).append(...)`, it will be quite messy to remove old values. Have you considered storing the data as an array instead and building the content dynamically each time the array changes?

Comment: @AjayGupta how do I share the HTML code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the `replace()` function to remove the name from the text field.

```js
$('input:checkbox').click(function() {
  var tb = "#" + $(this).attr('rel');
  let text_to_add = this.name + "\n";
  if ($(this).is(":checked")) {
    $(tb).append(text_to_add);
  } else {
    let remove = this.name + "\n";
    $(tb).text(function(i, text) {
      return text.replace(text_to_add, '');
    });
  }
})
```

Answer (score 0):

The following script assembles the checked checkboxes' `name` attribute values and places them into the textbox that is addressed by the checkbox's `rel` attribute:

```js
$('input:checkbox').click(function(){
    var tb = $(this).attr('rel');
     $("#"+tb).val($("[rel="+tb+"]:checked").map((i,e)=>e.name).get().join("\n"))

})
```

```css
textarea {height:50px}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<label><input name="one" type="checkbox" rel="mytext">one</label>
<label><input name="two" type="checkbox" rel="mytext">two</label>
<label><input name="three" type="checkbox" rel="mytext">three</label><br>
<textarea id="mytext"></textarea>
<br>
<label><input name="four" type="checkbox" rel="text2">4</label>
<label><input name="five" type="checkbox" rel="text2">5</label>
<label><input name="six" type="checkbox" rel="text2">6</label><br>
<textarea id="text2"></textarea>
```